# What's the term for a scene in a film designed to be shared on social media?

Tags: terminology, marketing

I read an article a few years ago talking about the influence of social media on filmmaking. They mentioned the phenomenon of how many films now include bite-sized scenes designed to be shareable as GIFs to help promote the movie (for instance the fistbump scene in the Big Hero 6 film and trailer).

The article named this kind of scene, I thought they called it a "tag", but I've been Googling and I can't find any reference to this concept nor can I remember where I read it. Can anyone help me out? Did I dream it?

Comment: There is something similar called Cinemagraphs

Comment: I needed this word to describe the My Little Pony bit (or w\e that pink pony stuffed animal is) in Suicide Squad. +1. I still don't know the story there; it's as if it was designed for me to ask about it online...

Answer (score 1):

I've always referred to them as *clips*. You see this most often on late shows where they interview actors or directors and at some point cut to a clip from whatever movie they're promoting. On the web you also see clips uploaded to youTube early on in a marketing campaign. It's very simple to turn these into gifs so that fans can share them through social media for viral marketing purposes.